# Rest services - login cookie

Tags: services, 8, redirection

I'm using Drupal 7.
When I POST request to remote site (services_endpoint/user/login) I am able to receive a session name and session id and all other information about user. After that when I open a tab in the same browser OR do automated redirect, I am not logged in to the remote website. I think I need to set cookie somehow to a browser. I try with setcookie($session_name, $sessid) but it's not working!

Any help?

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=drupal+rest+cookie&l=1

Comment: When I make a redirect from my app to remote site (user page for example) using the session returned form services I'm logged in ...I can see the user page as logged in user..but if I redirect to another location in the same browser I'm still not logged in.